# How to make messages not stretch before they scroll

Tags: html, css, material-design

We are creating a messenger with Google's Material and have the trouble that if you enter messages to a grid, the first message will fill the entire area, when adding a second one, both will take up half the page, this goes on until the messages can't get smaller until finally it starts to scroll. Then the scroll automation to scroll down works, but it looks stupid at the beginning.

not so good looking
[image: not so good looking]

This is what it looks like once the messages can't get smaller
[image: This is what it looks like once the messages can't get smaller]

```
 <div class="mdl-tabs__panel is-active chatbox" id="newest-panel">

       <section class="mdl-grid chatdiv">

          <div class=" chat mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--7-col-tablet mdl-cell--11-col-desktop">
            <div class="NameOfSender">Anton</div>
            <div class="ChatMessage">Inwiefern beeinflusst das autonome Fahren meinen Alltag?</div>
            <div class="Timestamp">- vor 3 min</div>
          </div>

    .chatbox{

  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 81vh;  
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chatdiv{

  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;   
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

$("#messagefield").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $("#messagefield")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
```

How can I fix this? 
IMPORTANT NOTE: The new messages are dynamically added via javascript!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should put your code into different code blocks while making a question, it looks like you put your css and js directly into html, which I think you didn't. The problem seems to be with your stylesheet, but I would need to see it in order to really know what style is causing that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the `max-height` attribute on `.chatbox`

```
.chatbox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 81vh;
  max-height: /*whatever suits*/; /* <-- Here is the fix*/
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chatdiv {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```